# How to config log4j 2 at a big project

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I need to config log4j2 in a big project, is possible setup it to get all exceptions from code without go in all classes? How..

Comment: This question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

If your code has `e.printStackTrace()` all over, then I'm afraid the answer is no. For the most part, you'll need to explicitly add a logger to your classes and use the `Logger` interface to send logs to your configured appender.

For example:

```
private static final Logger logger  = LogManager.getLogger(MyApplication.class.getName());
public void someMethod() {
    try {
       // business logic...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error connecting to database!", e);
    }
```